# Docusign webhook message does not have way to differentiate different compositetemplate

Tags: docusignapi

I have created 1 envelope with 2 composite templates with embedded signing and I can hook it up with the webhook event notification to receive a message once users finish signing, so I can try to update my db and download the file. However, the webhook response does not have the custom fields that I need to identify which file belong to which for me to update the db row.

**This is my json serialized envelope example. Notice the custom field on each inline template, that have the property of DocuInfoId. I will need the value of those to update my db row**

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Template Example",
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "https:\/\/mytestsite.net\/api\/documentstuff\/docusign\/available",
    "loggingEnabled": "false",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "soapNameSpace": "",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "false",
    "includeDocumentFields": "false",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent",
        "includeDocuments": null
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ],
    "recipientEvents": [
      {
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Client Name",
                "roleName": "Client",
                "tabs": {
                  "TextTabs": "Just a bunch of text tabs, radio group, etc"
                }
              },
              {
                "clientUserId": "2",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Owner Name",
                "roleName": "Owner",
                "tabs": null
              }
            ]
          },
          "customFields": {
            "ListCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "77",
                "listItems": null
              },
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "1",
                "listItems": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "TemplateIDNumber1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Client Name",
                "roleName": "Client",
                "tabs": {
                  "TextTabs": "Just another bunch of text tabs, radio group tab, etc"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "customFields": {
            "ListCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "88",
                "listItems": null
              },
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "1",
                "listItems": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "TemplateIDNumber2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**And once I finished signing, the webhook event notification is triggered and called my api with this response message**

```
{
  "EnvelopeStatus": {
    "EnvelopeID": "EnvelopeIDGivenByDocusign",
    "Status": "Completed",
    "CustomFields": [
      {
        "Name": "ContactID",
        "Show": "True",
        "Required": "False",
        "Value": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "OpportunityID",
        "Show": "True",
        "Required": "False",
        "Value": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "AccountID",
        "Show": "True",
        "Required": "False",
        "Value": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "DocuInfoId",
        "Show": "False",
        "Required": "True",
        "Value": "88"
      },
      {
        "Name": "OpportunityId",
        "Show": "False",
        "Required": "True",
        "Value": "1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "LQAID",
        "Show": "True",
        "Required": "False",
        "Value": ""
      }
    ],
    "DocumentStatuses": [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Document - TX - 1001.pdf",
        "TemplateName": "Document - TX",
        "Sequence": 1
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Rejection.pdf",
        "TemplateName": "Rejection Form",
        "Sequence": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "DocumentPDFs": [
    {
      "Name": "Document - TX - 1001.pdf",
      "DocumentID": "1",
      "DocumentType": "CONTENT"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Rejection.pdf",
      "DocumentID": "2",
      "DocumentType": "CONTENT"
    },
    {
      "Name": "CertificateOfCompletion_78sd89fuas89sadf.pdf",
      "DocumentID": null,
      "DocumentType": "SUMMARY"
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking at the response, there's only 1 docuinfoid with the value of 88, I'm also not sure where is the rest of custom field coming from e.g: "LQAID". Now, I'm not sure which docuinfoid is this belong to, the first pdf file (Document - TX - 1001.pdf) or the second pdf file (Rejection.pdf).

Is there anyway to know which pdf document belong to which docuinfoid, so that I can attach it to my database correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set compositeTemplateId for each CompositeTemplate and then use this Id in each envelope Custom Field. I have modified your JSON request to include CompositeTemplateId,

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Template Example",
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "https:\/\/mytestsite.net\/api\/documentstuff\/docusign\/available",
    "loggingEnabled": "false",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "soapNameSpace": "",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "false",
    "includeDocumentFields": "false",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent",
        "includeDocuments": null
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ],
    "recipientEvents": [
      {
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Client Name",
                "roleName": "Client",
                "tabs": {
                  "TextTabs": "Just a bunch of text tabs, radio group, etc"
                }
              },
              {
                "clientUserId": "2",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Owner Name",
                "roleName": "Owner",
                "tabs": null
              }
            ]
          },
          "customFields": {
            "ListCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId_1",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "77",
                "listItems": null
              },
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId_1",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "1",
                "listItems": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "TemplateIDNumber1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "email": "testemail@test.com",
                "name": "Client Name",
                "roleName": "Client",
                "tabs": {
                  "TextTabs": "Just another bunch of text tabs, radio group tab, etc"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "customFields": {
            "ListCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "DocuInfoId_2",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "88",
                "listItems": null
              },
              {
                "name": "OpportunityId_2",
                "required": "True",
                "show": "False",
                "value": "1",
                "listItems": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "TemplateIDNumber2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when you will receive WebHook response, you will be able to know which custom fields below to which composite template. I have one more suggestion, since you are not using any dropdowns, then it is better to use `TextCustomFields` instead of `ListCustomFields`.

Answer (score 0):

In DocuSign there are different types of *custom fields*.

- ***Envelope*** custom fields associate metadata with the Envelope as a whole.
- ***Document*** custom fields associate metadata with a specific Document in an Envelope.

To determine which type of custom fields your **Create Envelope** request is setting, you can execute the following requests for the envelope/document(s) and evaluate the results:

**Get Envelope Custom Fields**

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields`

**Get Document Custom Fields**

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/fields`

I'd suspect that perhaps your **Create Envelope** request is setting ***Envelope*** custom fields -- which associates that metadata with the Envelope as a whole, not with any specific document in the Envelope.

Based on what you've described, it sounds like you want to specify metadata for a particular document in an Envelope. If this is the case, you'll need to amend the structure/contents of your **Create Envelope** request to set ***Document*** custom field(s) (instead of setting ***Envelope*** custom fields).

Comment: Should I use the document property on composite template? If you look at my initial envelope request, I dont really have anything to put in documents though, everything is from server template and inline template. I just need a way to know the result in webhook response documentpdfs property belong to which one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the values from the `CustomFields` section of the XML, use the values contained in the `TabStatuses` elements.

You'll need to do a bit more parsing, but it gives you all the context info.

Comment: do you have any example? so the tabstatuses will be inside the inlinetemplate property? what will it look like when I got the message back from webhook envelope complete?