# Docusign field has blank value until it is clicked

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an envelope that has some field and the problematic field are this

```
"tabs":{"TextTabs":[{"TabLabel":"*SSN","Value":"*********"]
"NumberTabs":[{"TabLabel":"*MyNumber","Value":"0000000000"}]
```

All other fields are working fine that does not have "hide text with asterisk".

Those 2 fields on the docusign site itself "hide text with asterisk" are checked.

And the behaviour of those 2 fields are weird. When the envelope is sent, and I received a url for the docusign, when I open it, those 2 fields are empty (empty box), but when clicked.. it suddenly show the value, and when the box are out of focus then it will hide the text with asterisk.

My question is what should I do, so when docusign open, it was already on asterisk, without the user has to click the box first? Since the value was passed on, so technically the field already has value.

Comment: are you using DocuSign templates for creating envelopes? and while creating envelopes you are populating the masked fields using API?

Comment: Yes, I'm using docusign composite template.. and passing the value as part of the template.

Comment: One more thing, do you want to make this field editable or read only for the signer? As you are already populating the field using API and this field is masked, so I do not understand a reason for signer to click this field and do any edit. Also it will be great if you can share the complete envelope creation code using composite template, and we will try to replicate the same on our account.

Comment: the field is set up to editable. The envelope creation code is working fine, everything is working fine.. except those 2 fields. and if those 2 fields are setup to not "hide text with asterisk" it will work properly too.

Comment: Refer to my question on the same area about docusign https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667151/docusign-webhook-message-does-not-have-way-to-differentiate-different-compositet/47704810#47704810 the result of json envelope look like that. except the problematic 2 field I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The "masking", similar to the "validation" (regex), is applied by the UI (javascript). Since you are pre-populating, the javascript isn't invoked until the signer interacts with the tab overlay (UI). On click of the textbox, javascript is invoked and then on you see the asterix on the textbox. So functionally, it is hiding the text by being blank value on envelope signing page load.

Comment: so I guess, there's no way to fix this?

Comment: Not as of now, this is how it is implemented. As showing masked value means calling javascripts on the page load for each and every text tabs which might be performance issue.

Comment: Why you want field to hidden and prepopulated?